# update database value stored by using specific spinner value - android

Tags: android, database, spinner, updates

The task given to me is to "change the state(Spinner) value", for which I used spinner to select the specific state and it "directly stores its value in database".
Now I need to "Update the state" value.
Please help me.

Comment: simple, use update query as you use insert query

Comment: @bpAFree i need to get that spinner value from db and by using update button the value is shown as default spinner value of that spinner and then i have to update that spinner value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onItemSelectedListener of Spinner and in that you can update sqlite data